# Need to apply localisation for the API data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on flutter application that one should support localisation for multiple languages. I used to create .arb file for the localisation but for the API data i couldn't apply arb files ?

Comment: What is your API data? We need more informations. For example, if it's an error to be translated when an API call fails, then you could send along an error code and translate it in the arb files.

Comment: another way to translate is to use Google Translate API and render the Google Translate API translated response

Comment: @targiasld. My API data will be data of a user like profile data name, age, education,

Comment: Is this your own API? If yes, you can translate it in your backend

Answer (score 0):

### Here two ways make localization.

> 1. Use ARB (Application Resource Bundle) files

> 2. manage from API

## manage from Api

make API post method they past language code. they return all arb file data from the backend side.

and then store data in the local database and display all places you want display.

Comment: Is google translate package will work ?

Comment: its paid API is compatible with then is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

in Get Package you can extend the **translations** class and assign that class object to GetMaterialApp translations property,
You just need to get your Language Map files from API and pass to overrided keys function. For more please check doc https://pub.dev/packages/get#translations

API Response like

```
 res= {
            'en': {
              'SEARCH_FOR_SERVICES_AND_PROFESSIONALS':
                  'Search for services and professionals',
              'MEMBERSHIP': 'Membership',
              'PURCHASE': 'Purchase',
              'GET_STARTED': 'Get started',
              }
          }

 GetMaterialApp(
        title: Constants.appName,
        translations: Localization(res), //Localization class
```

and localization class

```
class Localization extends Translations {
  // final Map<String, Map<String, String>>? res;
  // Localization(this.res);
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => res
```